# What is the most efficient way to fill in a circle with a single brushstroke?

Tags: geometry

Given a brush with a circular tip of some finite size, and a circle, what is the shortest path that a single stroke of the brush can take so that every point within the circle is painted at least once?

I initially asked about this question with a brush of infinitesimal size (point sized) but it turns out that produces a path of infinite length, which makes sense in hindsight

Comment: I assume you want a brush size that is smaller than the radius of the circle?

Comment: sure. would it really make any difference mathematically though? the symbolic calculations would be the same until you plug in the numbers, wouldn't it?

Comment: You [asked a similar question a few days ago, and showed no effort](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133493/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-step-on-every-blade-of-grass-in-a-circular-fie).

Comment: If you paint along a $C^1$ curve of length $\ell$ with a circular brush stroke of radius $r$, the maximum area it can cover is $2\ell r + \pi r^2$ (a corollary of a result by Naiman, see [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlid=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176347010)) . To cover a circle of radius $R$, you need $\ell \ge \frac{\pi(R^2-r^2)}{2r}$. I don't know the actual optimal configuration but a spiral should give you something reasonably close to optimal.

Comment: If you draw in concentric circles - you can cover all the circle. Than turn it into a single brush by moving from one circle to the other. Start from the circumference with a circle half the brush radius.